# Getting undefined is not a function error react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I keep getting a "Render error, undefined is not a function" and I cannot figure out what is causing it. I am using flatlist, and my request json is returning in the format of

```
{
     "count": 3,
     "next": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/post?limit=1&offset=1",
     "previous": null,
     "results": [
        {
           "id": 0,
           "title": "title",
           "description": "description",
           "img": "https://linktoimage.jpg"
        }
     ]
}
```

My home

```
const Home = () => {

const { data, isLoading, isError, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage } =
 useFetchPost();
if (isLoading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>; 
if (isError) return <Text>An error occurred while fetching data</Text>;
const flattenData = data.pages.FlatMap((page) => page.data);

const loadNextPageData = () => {
 if (hasNextPage) {
   fetchNextPage();
 }
};

return (

  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    data={flattenData}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Post post={item} />}
    estimatedItemSize={2}
    onEndReached={loadNextPageData}
  />
 );
};export default Home;
```

Then useFetchPost

```
 import { useInfiniteQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
 export default function useFetchPost() {
 const getPosts = async ({ pageParam = 0}) => {
 const res = await (
  await fetch(
    `http://0.0.0.0:8000/post?limit=1&offset=${pageParam}`
  )
).json();   
 
return {
  data: res,
  nextPage: pageParam,
};
};  return useInfiniteQuery(['post'], getPosts, {
getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
        if (lastPage.data.length < 1) 
    return undefined;
  return lastPage.nextPage;
},
});
}
```

Lastly the error trace:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in Home (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by app)
    in QueryClientProvider (created by app)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by app)
    in app (created by withDevTools(app))
    in withDevTools(app)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

So far I have tried multiple solutions but nothing is working, I think it has an issue with getting the information from the item and I tried using a different return instead of the undefined in getNextPageParam in useFetchPost
Also I apologize for the bad formatting, I can fix it if there's something that harms understanding but so far I probably haven't caught everything.